# iracket can't find jupyter, even though it's already installed

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, installation, racket, raco

When trying to install the iracket kernel, it throws

```
cannot find jupyter executable
```

I already put python and racket in the PATH, I don't know if it helps but when entering the command `raco iracket check` it throws me

```
IRacket install-history file: "C : \\ Users \\ lenovo \\ AppData \\ Roaming \\ Racket \\ iracket.rktd "
  file exists ?: no
Cannot find jupyter executable.
```

my computer is windows 10.
i use pip to install jupyter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iracket install command needs to run the `jupyter.exe` command to find the directory where Jupyter kernels are stored. So you need to find where pip installed `jupyter.exe` and then add the directory containing `jupyter.exe` to your PATH, or you need to run the iracket install script with `raco iracket install --jupypter-exe path-to-jupyter.exe`.

Comment: it show me this `C:\Users\lenovo>raco iracket install --jupyter-exe path-to-jupyter.exe
Received non-zero exit code from jupyter command.`, and i already put in the path where is located the jupyter.exe

Comment: What happens if you run `path-to-jupyter.exe --data-dir` on the command line?

Comment: it said `"path-to-jupyter.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
program or executable batch file.`

Comment: Sorry, I meant replace "path-to-jupyter.exe" with the full path to the `jupyter.exe` executable. You need to find that first (I have no idea where pip installs things), and then tell `raco iracket install` about it using the `--jupyter-exe` option.

Comment: if it already worked, I had already tried but without putting the jupyter.exe in the address, although I had already put it in the path with the jupyter.exe